Can't get a bar graph ordered high to low without scrambling the rainbow colouring
I'm trying to get a bar plot ordered high values to low values, with the high values the start of the rainbow gradient and the low values the end of the rainbow. I can get them organized high to low OR in a proper rainbow gradient but not both, the colours keep on getting scrambled. I didn't switch the axis yet for the first one but would prefer the final graph to be the same orientation as the second graph pic.
p <-ggplot(Herb_Nums, aes(x = reorder(name, -amount), y = amount, fill = Herb_Nums$name), show.legend = FALSE) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) + theme(legend.position = "none")
p + theme(legend.position = "none")


df <- Herb_Nums %>% arrange(desc(amount))
ggplot(df, aes(x= name, y= amount, fill = Herb_Nums$name)) + geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) + coord_flip() + scale_color_continuous()


Thank you in advance!

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

To achieve your desired result map the reordered name column on the fill aes too.
Using some fake random example data:
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  name = LETTERS[1:20],
  amount = sample(20)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(
  x = reorder(name, -amount), y = amount,
  fill = reorder(name, -amount)
)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_continuous()


